# Else Statement Never Functions As Expected

Tags: arduino-uno, breadboard

I've been working on a rather simple Arduino-breadboard project, that is supposed to imitate a traffic light intersection. There are two sets of lights, one called the North-South lights, and then the East-West lights (quite similar to the traffic lights your would see at an intersection on the road). The goal is to get the traffic lights to turn their correct colors at the correct times; however, one of my yellow lights is not turning on at all, and the breadboard LEDs I'm using completely skip over the yellow light in question and go straight to the red-green configuratin that is supposed to happen after.

Here is the code I have:

```
void setup() {

  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); //R-ns
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //Y-ns
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //G-ns
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); //R-ew
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT); //Y-ew
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT); //G-ew

}

void loop() {

  for(int count = 0; count<16; count++) {
    
    if (count<7) {
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);      
      }

     else if (count==7) {
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);     
      }
      
     else if (7<count<15) {
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);      
      }
      
     else {
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);
      }
      
    delay(1000);
    }
    
}
```

As you can see, the North-South traffic light is supposed to turn on at the 16th second, except I don't see it happen on the physical LED. I don't understand why this is happening; can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: use serial.print() to debug your code

Answer (score 3):

`7<count<15` is interpreted as `(7<count)<15`.  `7<count` will result in a false or true, which will be interpreted as 0 and 1 when later involved in the `< 15` part of the expression, which means `7<count<15` is always true.

What you're probably looking for is `7 < count && count < 15`.